# Java REGEX - adding possibilities from a list

Tags: java, regex, string, list

I need advice for how to create a REGEX in the best way (with as little code as possible).
Suppose I have a list (that I don't know it's length before the running time) of Strings, say:

```
List<String> words = Array.asList("a","b","c");
```

I want to create this REGEX for example: `(a|b|c).*`
Is a loop necessary for this? Is there a way to do this in one line?

Thanks

Comment: There are better ways to do this than a regular expression.  Personally I would use `words.stream().anyMatch(text::startsWith)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single line:

```
String regex = words.stream().map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|", "(", ").*"));
```

The `map(Pattern::quote)` part is not necessary if you're *absolutely sure* that the "words" don't contain any regex-special characters. Keep it, if there is any microscopic chance it could happen.